# Find where results in columns from an array of column names in TypeORM

Tags: activerecord, typeorm

At the moment I have the following query:

```
return await this.siteRepository.find({
      where: [{ id: Like(`%${q}%`) }, { name: Like(`%${q}%`) }]
    });
```

But I would like to be able to pass a list of column names to be used for the query from an array and not write each one of them manually.

```
const columns = ["id","name", "lastName", "age"]
const query = {};
return await this.siteRepository.find({
          where: columns.map(column=>{(query[`${column}`] = `Like("%${q}%")}`)})
        });
```

Is this even possible? I'm starting to feel like it currently is not.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to accomplish what I wanted with the `Repository` TypeORM methods but I did manage to do it with the `QueryBuilder`

Here is my solution

`` const res = ['id', 'name'].map(item => `${item} LIKE :q`).join(' OR ');
return await this.siteRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .where(res, { q: `%${q}%` })
      .getMany(); ``

Which yields a query of

`` SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`name` AS `User_name`, `User`.`lastName` AS `User_lastName`, `User`.`active` AS `User_active` FROM `user` `User` WHERE name LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? ``